# postgres. plpgsql stack depth limit exceeded

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

im working on a simple function where it automatically updates something from a table.

```
create or replace function total() 
returns void as $$
declare
  sum int;
begin
  sum = (SELECT count(copy_id) FROM copies);
    update totalbooks
    set all_books = sum
    where num = 1;
  end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

if i execute "select total();" it works perfectly fine so i made a function trigger so that it automatically updates:

```
create or replace function total1() returns trigger as $$
begin
   perform (select total());
    return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

but after i execute this:

```
create trigger total2
after update
on totalbooks
for each row
execute procedure total1();
```

it gives me an error message:

```
ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 3072kB), after   ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT (SELECT count(copy_id) FROM copies)"
PL/pgSQL function total() line 5 at assignment
SQL statement "SELECT (select total())"
PL/pgSQL function total1() line 3 at PERFORM
SQL statement "update totalbooks
set all_books = sum
where num = 1"
PL/pgSQL function total() line 6 at SQL statement
SQL statement "SELECT (select total())"
PL/pgSQL function total1() line 3 at PERFORM
SQL statement "update totalbooks
set all_books = sum
where num = 1"
PL/pgSQL function total() line 6 at SQL statement
SQL statement "SELECT (select total())"
PL/pgSQL function total1() line 3 at PERFORM
SQL statement "update totalbooks
set all_books = sum
where num = 1"
PL/pgSQL function total() line 6 at SQL statement
SQL statement "SELECT (select total())"
PL/pgSQL function total1() line 3 at PERFORM
SQL statement "update totalbooks
set all_books = sum
where num = 1"
PL/pgSQL function total() line 6 at SQL statement
SQL statement "SELECT (select total())"
PL/pgSQL function total1() line 3 at PERFORM
SQL statement "update totalbooks
set all_books = sum
where num = 1"
PL/pgSQL function total() line 6 at SQL statement
SQL statement "SELECT (select total())"
PL/pgSQL function total1() line 3 at PERFORM
SQL statement "update totalbooks
set all_books = sum
where num = 1"
PL/pgSQL function total() line 6 at SQL statement
SQL statement "SELECT (select total())"
```

Obviously theres something wrong with my trigger. Please help.

I am using Postgres 9.2.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-Bit

EDIT:

i tried the pg_trigger_depth(), but now trigger doesn't automatically update?? i still have to execute 'select total()'

here's my new code:

```
create or replace function total() 
returns void as $$
declare
  sum int;
begin
   sum = (SELECT count(copy_id) FROM copies);
    update totalbooks
    set all_books = sum;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;


create or replace function total1() returns trigger as $$
begin
  perform (select total());
  return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger total2
after update
on totalbooks
for each row
WHEN (pg_trigger_depth()=0)
execute procedure total1();
```

Comment: Your trigger is fired by an update on `totalbooks` which then updates the table `totalbooks` which in turn fires the trigger on `totalbooks` which updates the table `totalbook` which fires the trigger on `totalbooks` which then updates the table `totalbooks` which then fires the trigger on `totalbooks` which updates the table `totalbook` which will fire the trigger ... (you get the picture)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so it's like doing things over and over and over again?? so how do i correct this one?? any ideas??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, if you really want the trigger on update, what you could do it set this trigger as column specific, so that it is not fired on an update to `all_books`, which is causing your recursion.  Something like this -

```
create trigger total2
after update of copy_id
on totalbooks
for each row
execute procedure total1();
```

Of course, you can change which columns trigger the function, I just chose `copy_id` because that is what you are counting.

HOWEVER

If you are updating with a `count()` result, you can just put the trigger on `INSERT` and `DELETE` actions.  This way the trigger will fire when the count changes, but will not itself be triggered by the update. // EDIT: Since your `sum` is only a count of all records in `copies`, it will only change when a record is inserted or updated, so running this trigger on update would not make sense anyway.

EDIT:  I figured it would be useful to add a link to the [CREATE TRIGGER Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtrigger.html).  See the section labeled "event", because this details how to specify columns in the event.

## EDIT FOR NEW INFORMATION:

Given what it sounds like you need to accomplish, I think you need to rethink your data design, I suggest you use a parent-child relationship (Anytime you are caching shared data on many rows in a table because they share something in common, that is a sign that you might need a parent table instead).

Have a `books` table where each row is information about one book (title, author, etc), and then have a `copies` table where each row holds information about one copy of a book (serial number, last checked out, etc).

That way, getting the count of copies is as simple as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM copies WHERE book_id=[some book id]`.

If you really want to cache the count somewhere, do it on the `books` table.

Create an `INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger on `copies` that does `UPDATE books SET copy_count=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM copies WHERE book_id=NEW.book_id) WHERE id=NEW.book_id`.

Then create a `DELETE` trigger on copies that does `UPDATE books SET copy_count=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM copies WHERE book_id=OLD.book_id) WHERE id=OLD.book_id`

The reason for two triggers is that the `NEW` variable is only available in `INSERT` or `UPDATE` triggers, and `OLD` is only available in `DELETE` triggers.  You could do it all as one trigger, but that requires more code than I wanted to put here.

Make sure all your triggers are `AFTER` triggers, or else a newly inserted/deleted row won't be considered in the count.

Comment: Okay im going to read it as soon as possible. Going to ask some questions after I read the link you gave me. Thank you.

Comment: Done reading and trying everything. I specified columns yet it still didnt update by itself.

Comment: What columns did you specify, and what SQL statement did you use to test the trigger?

Comment: `after update of all_books` and the sql statement to insert the trigger: `insert into copies(book_id) values('BI6');`

Comment: Your SQL is an `INSERT` statement, but your trigger is set to fire on `UPDATE`.  That SQL statement will never fire your trigger, you would have to update an existing row (something like `UPDATE copies SET book_id='BI6' WHERE ID=1`).  Also, thats what I was getting at in the second part of my answer - you probably want something like `AFTER INSERT OR DELETE` instead of `AFTER UPDATE` because you're doing a `count` with no constraints, and the result of that can only change after an insert or update.

Comment: Maybe I didnt get my own code in the first place. Okay so here's what i really wanted to do. if a copy of a book is added in the copies table, all_books must add 1 for each copy added or minus 1 for each copy removed. Is there any other way other than the one I made?? I'm kind of confused now.

Comment: I thought you might be looking to do something like that.  See my edit, and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Oh. Nevermind, you actually solved my problem. I used `AFTER INSERT OR DELETE FROM COPIES` instead of using totalbooks!! Great!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts! :))

Comment: Thats pretty much exactly what the second part of my original answer suggested you do.....

Comment: Yes, I actually did that part but I kind of typed the wrong table.

Answer (score 0):

Look into pg_trigger_depth:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-info.html

(9.2 or later)

Comment: T cant make it work?? how do i put pg_trigger_depth() in my functions??

Comment: add a check on the depth and return if it's recursive.

Comment: i edited my original post, and also posted the new code with the pg_trigger_depth() but im still not sure if i made the right code. can you check? please? thanks!

Comment: Inside your function, conditionally call perform total() if depth <= 1 (or maybe 2)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your trigger:

```
IF pg_trigger_depth() < 2 THEN

  PERFORM total();

END IF;
```